# How can I draw route from my location to destination location?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

Very recent i have to complete a project which have a small portion of Google map.
I drew route between two Geo points.
But i have to draw route from my Geo point to destination Geo point.
Here is an important note is that my location is not static.It will change with my position.And I have to draw route from this current position to destination.
Is it possible to draw such a dynamic route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
           Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +destLat+ ","+destLon+""));
 this.startActivity(i);
```

I guess it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html) to draw driving path in your application. You just need to add the four classes present in the link in your project and call the below lines when you need to display the route.

```
SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
data.setAPIKEY("0RUTLH7cqd6yrZ0FdS0NfQMO3lioiCbnH-BpNQQ");//set your map key here
data.setSrc_lat(17);//set your src lat
data.setSrc_lng(78);//set your src lng
data.setDest_lat(18);//set your dest lat
data.setDest_lng(77);//set your dest lng
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,RoutePath.class));//add RoutePath in your manifeast file
```

//Also add the permission to your manifeast file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: What type of permission i need to add?Please refer it

Comment: what about //add RoutePath in your manifeast file?which one need to add in manifest file?i do copy of your link ,make a project but it shows error :(

Comment: You mean route path is also an activity?

Comment: have you copied the four files in your project?

Comment: Ya.the four java files has been copied and did the whole process.but it still show the error message.

Comment: data.setSrc_lat(17);
        data.setSrc_lng(78);
        data.setDest_lat(18);
        data.setDest_lng(77); here the value you used is for your location?

Comment: replace that values with your values

Comment: Finally it proceed.but 1st it shows "Unable to find route".Then it shows"Fetching route,Please wait..." :(

Comment: data.setSrc_lat(17); data.setSrc_lng(78); in those lines i need to replace my Geo points.i do not know my Geo points.because they are not static.change with my position.so how can i get those values???????????

Comment: you can use gps to get those values